# Onclick event on textview(that has TextIsSelectable="true") is ony called on second click

Tags: java, android, android-intent, textview, onclicklistener

I have a `onClickListener` on a `textview` and the textview has the flag that it's `selectable`.
But the `onclick` event I specified is only called when the `textview` is clicked a second time.
After the second time it calles the onclick right, but if a other `textview` that also is `selectable` with a `onclicklistener` it also is only called the second time, then it works fine, but then the other one works only the second time again. I can't find the source of these weird events.

```
telefoonTXT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {startTelIntent();}}
);

urlTXT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {startWebIntent();}
});
```

Comment: Try out with `onTouchListener` on `TextView`. @Wesley Egbertsen

Comment: And besides setting the `TextIsSelectable="true"` set the `android:clickable="true"` for your TextView.

Comment: If I make them onTouchListeners, you cant select the text anymore because the onTouch get priority I think.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: I still have not found a solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I faced this issue as well. Whenever  text view is touched firstly `onTouch`, then `OnSelection` and at last `OnClick` is called.
If i understand your problem clearly you want to select text in text view when user `double taps` or `long presses` like the usual text selection but when user simply clicks it once u want the `onClick` to function. I think the following might help you.

Add a `gestureDetector` to your text View.

```
GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;
mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener());

mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(new GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        // This is where u add your OnClick event
        startTelIntent();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d("dtttt", "double tap");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }
});

telefoonTXT.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
          return false;
     }
});
```

Comment: Frosty's suggestion is the right direction to go. I can confirm it works for me.

Comment: It should be checked as answer. Works well.

Comment: It's important to really call your intended action in onSingleTapConfirmed() and not calling performClick(), which leads to problems the second time a user wants to select.

Comment: It really surprises me that `textIsSelectable` is so broken. Your solution works well, +1.

Comment: @mattlaabs, Can you elaborate the problem with calling `performClick()` from `onSingleTapConfirmed()`. I tried but everything seems to be working fine

Answer (score -1):

In my case focus change listener works, but be aware for cases when you use it in androidTv that you move with D-pad

```
textView.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
    if (hasFocus && textView.measuredHeight > textView.lineHeight * textView.lineCount) {
    //your click event               
    }
}
```

I check if text can be scrolled then don't take the click event

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer is good. But I had one additional issue with it: When I have some selection text in textview, I want to tap on textview to only deselecting the text - without perfoming on click listener. And perform on click only with no text selection.
So below is my solution:

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
public static void setOnClickGestureDetectorListener(TextView textView, Context context, View.OnClickListener onClickListener){
    if (textView == null || context == null || onClickListener == null)){
        return;
    }
    final GestureDetectorCompat detector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener());
    detector.setOnDoubleTapListener(new GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            onClickListener.onClick(textView);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if ( v instanceof TextView ) {
                TextView textView = (TextView)v;
                if (textView.getSelectionStart() >= 0 && textView.getSelectionEnd() > textView.getSelectionStart()){
                    return false;
                }
                detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

And calling example is below:

```
setOnClickGestureDetectorListener(textView, getContext(), new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //  This is where u add your OnClick event     
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score -3):

set this ...

```
TextisSelectable = "false"
```

i think it will be work correctly

Comment: Then it will work correctly but I also want the text to be selectable.