# using onClick on TextView with selectable text - how to avoid double click?

Tags: android, onclick, textview, onclicklistener

This is so strange, but if you put an onClickListener on a **TextView** (or non-editable EditText) which has  `android:textIsSelectable="true"` - it needs not one tap, but two.
I checked it on 3 phones and all of them perform ***onClick*** only after second tap.

Of course, if you make `focusable="false"` or `android:textIsSelectable="false"` it works from the 1st tap, but text selection doesn't work.

Please, help me with that issue

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Any solution to this yet?

Comment: this answer works for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35221862/908821

Answer (score 4):

Set in XML to your `TextView`:

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

After that set `onTouchListener` to your `TextView` and in them do this:

```
if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) view.requestFocus();
```

It's set focus for every tap on `TextView`.
After all set `onClickListener` to your `TextView`.

I have the same problem with a `ViewHolder` in my `RecyclerView.Adapter`. So, I cut it for you if you need:

```
class RollHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnTouchListener {

    private TextView textView;

    RollHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textView.setOnClickListener(this);
        textView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.text_view:
                // Do here that you need
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.text_view:
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) view.requestFocus();
                break;
        };
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it's hard to ask and search for a resolution.

Here are two things that I noticed in addition to the double tap behavior:

- if you really double tap (quickly) on a TextView with `textIsSelectable`, it selects the word you tapped, even when the focus is on something else, which means the view somehow registered the first touch as well.
- if you long tap while the focus is somewhere else, it works and starts the selection action mode as if it was focused already

Here's how I managed to make it work. It's not beautiful, but everything works fine so far: in the XML you only need to add `textIsSelectable`, no other `focusable` / `focusableInTouchMode` / `clickable` / `enabled` attributes needed; then **you need two listeners, one is the existing `onClick` which works, but needs a double take and the other is an `onFocusChange` where you handle the exceptional first tap**:

```
hint = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.hint);
hint.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        handleHintClick();
    }
});
hint.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) { handleHintClick(); }
    }
});
```

Here is an [alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28712076/253468) in a related question which I don't like and didn't even try: wrap the TextView in a FrameLayout and add the listener to that.

Here is another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11790573/253468) which has more solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `onTouchListener` to detect clicks and redirect them to the container view:

```
textView.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
    if (event.action == 1 && !textView.hasSelection()) {
        containerView.callOnClick()
    }
    false
}
```

This will keep the ability to select and unselect text without calling `onClick` event.

Answer (score -1):

```
android:longClickable="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

Disable the button with `setEnabled(false)` until it is safe for the user to click it again.

[May this helpful to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608720/android-preventing-double-click-on-a-button)

Comment: Double click is not an unwanted user interaction here, it's an unwanted Android behavior, and as such he wants to "avoid" the system forcing the user to do it and not "prevent" the user from doing so.

Answer (score -3):

Try this.

use in XML file

```
    android:onclick"your Name"//for example I used "onImageListClick"

    public void onImageListClick(View view)
        {
             //do your task.
            //Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageListActivity.class);
            //intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, IMAGES);
            //startActivity(intent);
        }
```

or

```
  txtboxname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
////do you task.
       }        
});
```

Comment: Of course that's what I do. but with android:textIsSelectable="true" it needs 2 clicks instead 1 to work . try it yourself